# Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with probability density function. Find marginal density and probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with probability density function:

$\;f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
\frac15, & for\;(x,y)\in [0,5]\times [0,1]\\
0, & otherwise \\
\end{array} \right. $

$(a)$ find marginal density of $X$

$(b)$ $P(Y<\frac12)=$?

$(c)$ find if $X$ and $Y$ are independent

---

$(a)$ $f_X(x)=\int_R f(x,y)\;dy = \int_0^1 \frac15dy = \frac15 \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$

$(b)$ $P(Y< \frac12)=\int_0^{\frac12} \frac15dy=\frac15(\frac12)=\frac{1}{10}$

$(c)$ ?

Please help with $(c)$ and check the above. Will be grateful.

Comment: For (a)  the indicator function on the interval $[0,5]$. I think you confuse $X$ with $Y$ at (b). For (c)  what is the definition of independent R. V.?

Comment: $(a)$ $f_X(x)=\int_R f(x,y)\;dy = \int_0^ \frac15dy = \frac15 \mathbf{1}_{[0,5]}(x)$ and that's all?
according to $(c)$ $f_X(x)*f_Y(y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y) $?

Comment: Yes! Just find $f_X$ and $f_Y$ and compare the product with $f_{X, Y} $

Comment: I already kind of know how to calculate $f_X$ and $f_Y$, looking at (a), but I don't know how to calculate $f_{X,Y}$.
And I think I don't know what do you mean in (b)...

Comment: you already have $f_{X, Y} $ that is just the joint density. For (b) , is $\frac{1} {5} $ the density of $Y$? No, what is it then?

Comment: If it isn't just $g(y)=\frac15 , for\; y \in [0,1]$, I don't really know.

Comment: you know how to find marginal densities. You have done it (almost) correctly for $X$ why you can't do it for $Y$? Just follow the same steps. Integrate the joint density over all values of $x$

Comment: I think that I misunderstood you. Anyway $f_Y(y)=\int_R f(x,y)\; dx = \int_0^5 \frac15 dx= 1*\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(y)$

Comment: that is correct! I guess now you can find (b)  and (c)  easily?

Comment: (c) $X,Y$ are independent.
(b) $P(Y< \frac12)=\int_0^{\frac12} 1 dy=\frac12$ am I right?

Comment: Yes!! Well done!

Comment: Would be nice if you edit the post to include the corrected answers. It is good to know for other users that you know the answer without having to read all these comments. Have a nice day!

Comment: I will do it in the future if you wish, but I have to much work to do yet, exams are coming...

I would also like to ask, if I understand it, that $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x,y)dydx=\frac52$ ?

Comment: that is correct!

Comment: I believe it's the last question to this type of problem: Random variable Y has unvarying distribution on $[0,1]$. I mean I don't know how to do this. the answer is not just: false? Everything I need is a density, given in the task?